# get text value in xpath without including scripts

Tags: xpath, web-scraping

Hello I am new to web scraping and X PATH in general, I have the following x path which I use in scrapy (python framework) in the ID `main`,how can I modify the xpath to not collect texts that are in "scripts" and "styles"?

```
my_list=response.xpath('//*[@id="main"]//text()').extract()
```

After searching online I found that I can use `|` to put more than one x path (in my case specific to each tag)but this isn't efficient as the text can be in any tag span,li,h2...

I.e I want to extract all text in id=main but not from script or style tags

Comment: This would be easier to reason about if you'd provide the relevant part of `response`.

Comment: @ldz you can try on any amazon product or eBay product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `name()` function to get the name of the node, and the `not()` function to specify which ones you do not want to include:

```
//*[@id='main']/descendant-or-self::*[not(name()='script') and not(name()='style')]//text()
```

`descendant-or-self` ensures that any text node directly on `//*[@id='main']` gets included as well.